# "Waterfall" style line plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written a script that takes hundreds of xy dataframes and plots them on a single plot. They are offset from each other simply by a linear function on the index of the dataframe. What I would like to do though is give "priority" to the frames with lower indices, such that any frame with a higher index "passes behind" the earlier one. Something like the attached image:
[waterfall plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Tf0.png)

This is what my script currently generates:
[current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F863Z.png)

Here's the raw code for the part that plots the data:

```
plot_dfs <- function(dfs,color,xxx=c(2,30), yyy) {
  # Initialize an empty ggplot object
  p <- ggplot() + 
    theme_minimal() +
    xlab("Angle") + ylab("Intensity") + xlim(xxx) + ylim(yyy)+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
  
  # Add a separate line plot for each data frame
  for (i in seq_along(dfs)) {
    p <- p + geom_line(data = dfs[[i]], aes(x = Angle, y = Intensity, color = as.factor(i)), size = 1, alpha = 0.7)
  }
  
  # Adjust color gradient for all plots
  colors <- rev(colorRampPalette(c(color))(length(dfs)))
  p <- p + scale_color_manual(values = colors)
  
  return(p)
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The example plot adds a fixed y value to each data series so that they are separated.

Comment: I do that with mine too in the actual longer data processing script. But if you look closely at the example, you'll see that if a line crosses behind another line (peak), it vanishes. that's what I want

Comment: Try `geom_area` with a white fill instead of `geom_line`. It's difficult to actually show you how to do this without a [mre], which is really a prerequisite for a good question on Stack Overflow.